# How can I make javascript interact with my smartcontract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

For instance, there is this website where people can create their tokens/ICOs.
https://tokenmint.io/app/#/ico
All they have to do is filling the blank spaces and I suspect it's written directly into a smartcontract.

How can one do that?

Comment: Your question is too broad. These kinds of questions are more suited to, e.g., Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Frontend interaction with smart contract is dealt by

- A core library like web3.js or ethers.js
- A wallet provider like MetaMask, etc.
- A hosted Ethereum node where you can query the smart contract status (QuikNode, Infura)

More information in this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-a-user-to-your-dapp-web3-js-project